# Search for values in a subform (vba Access2013)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an open subform (within a form).The subform is based on a query and contains several records. I want to search the subform to find whether any records have a field value that = true.

After searching the best suggestion was to use sql. This is what I'm working with:-

```
Dim iRecCount As Integer
Dim strRecCount As String
Dim vInvoiceID as Variant

vInvoiceID = [Forms]![Invoices]![InvoiceID].Value


strRecCount = "SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfSlotID FROM (Appointments INNER JOIN Students ON Appointments.StudentID = Students.StudentID) INNER JOIN Invoices ON Appointments.InvoiceID = Invoices.InvoiceID WHERE (((Appointments.InvoiceID)=" & vInvoiceID & ") AND ((Students.PAYG)=Yes));"

iRecCount = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strRecCount).Fields(0).Value

If iRecCount > 0 Then
    [Forms]![Invoices]![Temp Termly].Value = True
Else: [Forms]![Invoices]![Temp Termly].Value = False
End If
```

If I copy and paste the SQL string in a query it gives me the correct results (In fact a got the SQL string from a working query). However this code returns zero no matter what. I think there is something wrong with this line:-

```
iRecCount = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strRecCount).Fields(0).Value
```

Any suggestions or alternative solutions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the RecordsetClone:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim Found As Boolean

Set rs = Me!SubformControlName.Form.RecordsetClone
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.FindFirst "[Temp Termly] = True"
    Found = Not rs.NoMatch
End If
Set rs = Nothing

If Found = True Then
    ' Success.
End If
```